# Javascript snake game, configurable section distance

Tags: javascript, movement, snake

I want to make a snake game.
In a classic game the snake moves in 4 directions, I want the player to move in all directions by mouse input, similar to slither.io

Right now the tail section changes its position after the head.
If I increase the speed, the sections move away from each other.
How can I make the sections not move away from each other and have a configurable distance between them?

Code snippet:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Change speed of movement
var speed = 5.0

var mouseMovementX = 0;
var mouseMovementY = 0;

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event){
 mouseMovementX = event.clientX;
 mouseMovementY = event.clientY;
}); 


var key = {
 a: false,
 s: false
}

function keyboard(){
 //$(window).keydown(function(event){
 document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if( event.which == 83 ){
   key.s = true
  } 
  if( event.which == 65 ){
   key.a = true
  } 
 });
document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
 //$(window).keyup(function(event){
  if( event.which == 83 ){
   key.s = false
  } 
  if( event.which == 65 ){
   key.a = false
  } 
 });
}


function drawCircle(x, y, rotation){
 ctx.moveTo(x, y);
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(x,y,12,0,Math.PI*2,false);
 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.fill();
 ctx.strokeStyle = "#ccc";
 ctx.stroke();
} 

function radToDeg(value){
 return ( value * 180 ) / Math.PI;
}

function degToRad(value){
 return ( value * Math.PI ) / 180;
}

// Clamp
function clamp(Ax,Ay,Bx,By,L){   
 var Vx = Bx - Ax;
 var Vy = By - Ay;
 
 var lmax = L;
 var l = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(Vx,2) + Math.pow(Vy,2) );
 
 var lclamp = Math.min( l, lmax );
 
 var vclampX = ( Vx / l ) * lclamp 
 var vclampY = ( Vy / l ) * lclamp 
 
 var bclampX = Ax + vclampX
 var bclampY = Ay + vclampY

 return { x: bclampX, y: bclampY  }
}


// Update tail
function updateTail(i){
 for( i2 = app.object[i].body.length-1; i2 >= 0; i2--){
  if( i2 == 0 ){      
   var r = clamp(
    app.object[i].head.x,
    app.object[i].head.y,
    app.object[i].body[i2].x,
    app.object[i].body[i2].y,
    app.object[i].sectionDistance
   ); 
     
   app.object[i].body[i2].x = r.x 
   app.object[i].body[i2].y = r.y
  }else{
   var r = clamp(
    app.object[i].body[i2-1].x,
    app.object[i].body[i2-1].y,
    app.object[i].body[i2].x,
    app.object[i].body[i2].y,
    app.object[i].sectionDistance
   ); 
     
   app.object[i].body[i2].x = r.x
   app.object[i].body[i2].y = r.y
  }
 }
}

// Update previous positions
function updatePrevPosition(i){
 app.object[i].head.xPrev = app.object[i].head.x
 app.object[i].head.yPrev = app.object[i].head.y
 app.object[i].head.anglePrev = app.object[i].head.angle
}

var app = {
 object: []
}

// Create snake object
var options = {
 size:0,
 length:20,
 width: 24,
 height: 24,
 sectionDistance: 10,
 head: {
  x: 200,
  y: 200,
  xPrev:0,
  yPrev:0,
  angle: 0
 },
 body: []
}

app.object.push(options)

for( i = 0; i <  app.object[0].length;i++){
 app.object[0].body.push({ 
  x: (6*i)+200,
  y: (6*i)+200,
  angle: 0,
  color:0
 })
}


// Draw
var numberOfObjects = app.object.length;

function draw(){
 for( i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++ ){
  if( i == 0 ){
   for( i2 = app.object[i].body.length-1; i2 >= 0; i2-- ){ 
    drawCircle((canvas.width/2)+( app.object[i].body[i2].x - app.object[i].head.x) ,(canvas.height/2)+( app.object[i].body[i2].y - app.object[i].head.y ),app.object[i].body[i2].angle)
   }
   
   drawCircle((canvas.width/2),(canvas.height/2),app.object[i].head.angle)
  }else{
   var tempX = ( app.object[i].head.x - app.object[0].head.x ) + ( canvas.width / 2 )
   var tempY = ( app.object[i].head.y - app.object[0].head.y ) + ( canvas.height / 2 )

   drawCircle(tempX,tempY,app.object[i].head.angle)
  }
 }
}

// Update positions
function update(){

 if( key.a == true ){
  speed -= 0.1;
  if(speed < 0.1 ){ speed = 0.1 }
  console.log(speed)
 }
 if( key.s == true ){
  speed += 0.1;
  if( speed > 10 ){ speed = 10 }
  console.log(speed)
 }      
       
       
       
 angle = ( Math.atan2(mouseMovementX - ( canvas.width / 2 ) , mouseMovementY - ( canvas.height / 2 )) * -1 );
 
 newX = Math.sin(angle) * speed
 newY = Math.cos(angle) * speed

 app.object[0].head.angle = angle 

 app.object[0].head.x -= newX 
 app.object[0].head.y += newY 
 
 updateTail(0)
 updatePrevPosition(0)
  
 draw();
}

keyboard();
// Animate
function animate(){
 ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
 requestAnimationFrame(animate);
 update();  
}
animate();
```

```css
html, body{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 background-color:blue;
}
canvas{
 display:block;
 background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: This type of 'open ended' question would benefit very heavily from a video/gif, or a picture of what is happening right now, and an illustration of what you want to happen.

Comment: Presumably you've checked through previous Q&A in the [tag:snake] tag for starting points here? Or [looked up a snake tutorial for JavaScript](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+snake+tutorial)?

Comment: I went through the results on Google and Stack Overflow, I didn't find
an explanations of how to make the distance between sections configurable 
that works with variable speed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Take a vector from segment A to segment B

2)Calculate vector length

3)Check if length exceeds maximum, clamp if it does

4)Normalize vector and multiply it by clamped length

5)Set position of segment B to position of A + clamped vector

Desmos graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eilpcyx5gp

**EDIT:** Since segments depend on each other's position during clamping, you should go from head to tail, not from tail to head. Rewrite your loop accordingly:

`for( i2 = 0; i2 < app.object[i].body.length; i2++){`

Comment: I made it work, but after increasing the speed of movement the distance between sections still increases. I updated the snippet to see the effect, use keys "A" and "S" to increase/decrease the speed

Comment: @Freeman123 just ran the demo and it seems to me like you apply clamping to only two segments, algorithm should be applied to each segment

Comment: The clamping is applied to all segments. In "updateTail()" function, the second part of the condition is where the positions for the rest of the segmens are calculated.

Comment: @Freeman123 I really shouldn't have debugged your code but I updated the answer with the result.